# Sprinkler system 1st zone just started to recycle when turned on all others work fine

Tags: repair, landscaping, sprinkler-system, irrigation

1st zone just started to recycle ... pressure gauge is up and down quickly system is set to 50/30 cutoff.  Yes all heads in zone 1 are working and putting out proper sprinkler spray however pump keeps constant recycling
( ONLY ZONE 1).

I am afraid that this will burn out pump if allowed to continue...What is the fix, please? All other zones are working fine all heads putting out proper water.

Comment: Great, some photos of the setup, showing the layout, brand, model etc would help others to answer your question.

Comment: has this posted?

Comment: A little more clarity of your situation.  Are you running a sprinkler system on a well?  Is it just an irrigation well?  What HP for that?  What type of spray heads on the problem zone?  Please give more details.

Comment: What is zone one recycling?

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say the zone valve did not open.

Comment: This desperately needs an [edit] to include brand/model of the items in question as well as pics of the effected items, wiring to them, etc. _You_ know what you're talking about, but all _we_ can see is words on a screen. Help us help you.

Comment: it is an irrigation well only. has 4 zones . with rainbird controller, has 6-8 rainbird 5000 sprinkler  heads  in each zone . system was working fine no problems  then i noticed that the 1st zone started to constantly recycle .. all the other zones are fine still working .. constant recycling will burn out pump motor (1/2 hp) so that is my concern.. I am leaning to a clog in zone one  .. am going to one at a time check from the further head from the pump in zone 1 for clogs of each head feed working back toward the pump ..

Comment: The information in your comment needs to be [edit]ed into your Question. We still need more information: layout, equipment involved...